# Display link image from database for Restfull api

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, api

I use codeigniter to manage restfull api and using Rest Server Library, all data can display but i want to know how to add link target for image that loaded from database?

For example i have results from api:

```
[
    {
        "id_news": "1",
        "cat_news": "1",
        "title": "news title",
        "content": "this is content",
        "media": "5350_13.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id_news": "2",
        "cat_news": "1",
        "title": "news title 2",
        "content": "this is content 2",
        "media": "5350_16.jpg"
    }
]
```

But i want to add link in "media" like http://domain.com/media/"media_result"

in my controller

```
function contents_get()
{
    $data_news = $this->query->getall();
    $this->response($data_news);
}
```

Model

```
function getall()
{
$query = $this->db->get("news");
return $query->result();
}
```

How can i do that?

Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by _"i want to add link in 'media' like domain.com/media/'media_result'"_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not mistaken, you want to add a URL to your media value for each result. In that case, I would loop through the results, modify them as you wish, then return them. Try something like this:

```
function getall() {
    $query = $this->db->get("news");
    $result = $query->result();
    foreach ($result as $res){
        $media = $res->media;
        $res->media = "http://something.com/media/$media";
    }
    return $result;
}
```